# How to pipe text into command with promisified node exec

Tags: node.js, bash, jar, pipe, child-process

I am using node to execute a jar file that usually takes a CSV file as an input path.

I would like to try and circumvent writing the CSV file and pipe in the CSV as a string into the process if possible.

I have this working with `execSync` but I would prever to use `exec` wrapped with `promisify`

The problem is that `exec` does not have the `input` option like `execSync` so I can't pipe data into it. How do you get around this? Or is the best practice to wrap `execSync` in a `Promise`?

```
import {execSync} from 'child_process';


export const runJar = async (input: string, cwd: string) => {

const out = execSync(`java -jar model.jar`, {
    cwd,
    input,
})

  return out.toString('utf-8');
};
```

Comment: Does your java code read from "stdin" ? Also note, "execSync" is not capable to pipe something into the child process. use exec instead

Answer (score 2):

Minimalistic example usage of a childs process stdio.

- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

```js
const child_process = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");

// exec returns a child process instance
// https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess
const child = child_process.exec("cat");


// write to child process stdin
child.stdin.write("Hello World");

// to read/parse your csv file
//fs.createReadStream("./file.csv").pipe(child.stdin);


// listen on child process stdout
child.stdout.on("data", (chunk) => {

    console.log(chunk);
    child.kill();

});
```

To promisfy this, you can listen on the exit (status) on the child process and resolve or reject the promise based on the exit code:

```js
child.on("close", (code) => {

    if (code != 0) {
        reject();
    } else {
        resolve();
    }

});
```

Example given:

```js
const readParseCSV = function (file = "./file.csv") {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const child = child_process.exec("java -jar model.jar");
        fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(child.stdin);

        let response = "";


        // listen on child process stdout
        child.stdout.on("data", (chunk) => {
            response += chunk;
        });

        
        child.on("close", (code) => {

            if (code != 0) {
                reject();
            } else {
                resolve(response);
            }

        });

    });
};
```

Im not sure if this works on windows the same way as on linux.